# Unable to open a file using System.IO.File.OpenText(file path) in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Please find the updated code. Here i am trying to open a file which exists. Here is the code snippet. 
sample.txt is to get the complete file path. I am manually using that path and able to open the text file. But through code i am unable to open it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //to search for a file in folder
            String name_of_file = textBox1.Text;
            String search_file = @"D:\Shreyas\" + name_of_file + ".txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\Shreyas\\sample.txt", search_file);

            //search and open the file
            if(System.IO.File.Exists(search_file))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Found!!");

                System.IO.File.OpenText(search_file);
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Doesn't Exist!!");

            }
        }
```

Comment: `D:\\\\Shreyas\\\\shreyas.txt` is not a valid path.

Comment: Try `"D:\\Shreyas\\shreyas.txt"` instead of `"D:\\\\Shreyas\\\\shreyas.txt"`

Comment: Are you able to find the file and not open it, or can you simply not find it? Dumping a snippet of code into a SO question doesn't mean it's a question, please tell us what you've tried and what you need help with.

Comment: @Jay Gould I am new to stackoverflow so my question may look incomplete. Anyway I am able to find the path and everything. I am just unable to open the file. I am going to try @ before the path and update the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited Version:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to search for a file in folder
        String name_of_file = "Test";
        String search_file = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\" + name_of_file + ".txt";
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\Shreyas\\sample.txt", search_file);

        //search and open the file
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(search_file))
        {
            string tmp = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\" + name_of_file + ".txt").ReadLine();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test_Write.txt", tmp);
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Doesnt Exists");

        }
    }
```

This will read and write the file onto another file.

Try: `@"D:\Shreyas\shreyas.txt"`

The @ symbol in the beginning of the string tells C# that it's a path he needs to use and will format it correctly for you :)

EDIT:

Just saw it on your comment. To Read it use this:

`string tmpString = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\" + name_of_file + ".txt").ReadLine());`

Also, don't forget to dispose your Filereader. If you dont do that, you wont be able to Edit your file while your application is running.`

To open the text file try `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(search_file);`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the file is still not opening with all the changes.

Comment: @user1967685 While you where writing your comment I edited my solution :D I added how you can load your file text onto a string.

Comment: no luck!! Still unable to open a text file. I don't know y this basic functionality is not working

Comment: @user1967685 maybe give us some more information? Got any error messages? Is the string null? Maybe wrong filename?

Comment: I am printing the value of search_file into another text file... It's give a correct path and when I am manually using that path the file is opening but through code it's not.

Comment: @user1967685 you put it into another file? Maybe edit your post to show us the updated code. :)

Comment: @user1967685 the `.WriteAllText()` Method wants the path to the file it needs to write into and a `string` with the content you want to write. On your code you try to write the path to the file you want to read. You need to do this after you opened and saved the content from the file you want to read. Look up my edited post for the final solution.

Comment: I tried this. Its writing the content into another file. I can't open any file just to read? Like how we double click and open a file.

Comment: @user1967685  well, next time ask exactly what you want.

Comment: @user1967685 I added how to launch a file into my solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help. I have just started working on C#. I am sorry to ask so many questions. Thanks a lot again for all your help...

Comment: @user1967685 no problem :) but just try to write all the things you want or wont work into the question. It would have gave you a working solution way faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
string path = @"D:\Shreyas\shreyas.txt";
System.IO.File.OpenText(path);
```